# jquery ui droppable drop element on doc ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have #selector and li's that are droppable. On $(document).ready(); I would like to have the #selector be dropped into the second li.... In a perfecto world the code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selector').dropInto($('ul li').eq(1));
});
```

But unfortunately the world is not perfect, and that's why we have stack overflow.

Comment: Why you just don't call the 'on_drop' handler manually ?

Comment: isnt it ... $('#selector').drop($('ul li').eq(1));

Comment: @Nelson could you explain a little more?

Comment: @Wardy - there is no method .drop()

Comment: Post all your code so I can comment in context.

Comment: sorry i took too long ... user1114096 is correct, that is exactly how it works ... you basically say "$(this thing)" ".droppable({})" is droppable, and when dropped on do this "drop: function() {}" by simply calling a function drop: codeExecuteOnDrop($('ul li').eq(1)); you can reuse that function at any point (like in the below example in document ready)

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved this by placing the drop code into a separate function (an answer I've seen before) but the trick was to pass in the object that I was simulating the drop onto. Here's some sample code:

```
function codeExecutedOnDrop(element){
    element.addClass('blah').fadeIn();
}

$('ul li').droppable({
    drop: function() {
        codeExecutedOnDrop($(this));
    }
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    codeExecuteOnDrop($('ul li').eq(1));
});
```

Thanks to Nelson and Wardy for trying to help!